# Error al rellenar un Array multidimensional

Tags: java, array, arraylist, tablas

Viendo que me salian las cosas "sencillas" he decidido complicar un poco mas la cosa y hacer un programa que solicite al usuario 3 paises y después 3 ciudades de los mismos, para almacenarlos en una tabla y luego mostrar la tabla. El codigo que he planteado es el siguiente:

```
public class Ejer3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\t Aprendiendo Geografia");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        String tabla[][] = new String[3][4];

        String p1, p2, p3, ciudad;

        System.out.print("Introduce el primer pais: ");
        p1 = teclado.nextLine();
        tabla[0][0] = p1;

        System.out.print("Introduce el segundo pais: ");
        p2 = teclado.nextLine();
        tabla[1][0] = p2;

        System.out.print("Introduce el tercer pais: ");
        p3 = teclado.nextLine();
        tabla[2][0] = p3;

        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce la ciudad de " + p1 + ": ");

                ciudad = teclado.nextLine();
                tabla[i][j] = ciudad;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce la ciudad de " + p2 + ": ");

                ciudad = teclado.nextLine();
                tabla[i][j] = ciudad;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce la ciudad de " + p3 + ": ");

                ciudad = teclado.nextLine();
                tabla[i][j] = ciudad;

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabla[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(tabla[j][j]);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

El caso es que me deja introducir todo por teclado correctamente como podeis ver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La duda o el error que quiero corregir es, almacenar correctamente los paises y las ciudades en una tabla, ya que con el codigo de arriba, me deja meter todo correctamente, paises y ciudades, pero al mostrar la tabla da un error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at arraysN.Ejer3.main(Ejer3.java:67)
C:\Users\jorge\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2rc\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 33 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes unos cuantas cosas que podrías cambiar en tu código. Te dejo primero el código y luego procedo a la explicación:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("\t Aprendiendo Geografia");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    String tabla[][] = new String[3][4];

    String p1, p2, p3, ciudad;

    System.out.print("Introduce el primer pais: ");
    p1 = teclado.nextLine();
    tabla[0][0] = p1;

    System.out.print("Introduce el segundo pais: ");
    p2 = teclado.nextLine();
    tabla[1][0] = p2;

    System.out.print("Introduce el tercer pais: ");
    p3 = teclado.nextLine();
    tabla[2][0] = p3;

    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            System.out.print("Introduce la ciudad de " + tabla[i][0] + ": ");

            ciudad = teclado.nextLine();
            tabla[i][j] = ciudad;

        }
        System.out.println("");

    }



    for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tabla[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(tabla[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Voy a tomar el primer índice como columna y el segundo como fila para mi explicación, aunque se suele hacer al revés, solo para que el dibujito de abajo quede cuadrado

Según entiendo, planeas almacenar el país en la primera columna, y luego, en cada columna restante, almacenar sus ciudades:

> ```
> pais1 | cuidadP1-1 | cuidadP1-2 | cuidadP1-3
> pais2 | cuidadP2-1 | cuidadP2-2 | cuidadP2-3
> pais3 | cuidadP3-1 | cuidadP3-2 | cuidadP3-3
> ```

El primer bucle para almacenar los países los tienes bien.

Luego, en lugar de hacer 3 bucles para cada país, te vale con solo uno, imprimiendo el nombre del país con `tabla[i][0]`. Tu sabes que conforme avance i desde 0 hasta 3 accederás a cada fila de cada país, y que en la posición 0, siempre tendrás el nombre del país que estés almacenando.

Luego, para guardar los datos, haces que j vaya desde 1 (*ya que en 0 esta el nombre de país*) hasta 3, almacenando las 3 ciudades. En este punto, sería mejor ir desde `j=1` hasta `j<tabla[i].lenght`, para que, si decides ampliar el número de ciudades a almacenar, no tengas que modificar manualmente el código, *tenlo en cuenta*.

Luego, a la hora de imprimir, imprimías `tabla[j][j]` en lugar de `tabla [i][j]`.

Cualquier duda me avisas, un saludo.

> **PD:** Si en el país 1 imprime las ciudades 1 y 2 cambiadas es pq me lie yo al hacer la entrada nada más :P
>
> **PD2:** Aunque comentas que te dejaba hacer la entrada sin problemas, esto es falso. Aunque no te tirase error, tu entrada de ciudades estaba mal planteada. No entendí muy bien que querías hacer con este bucle: `for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {`

Comment: Muchas gracias Rodrigo, me has sigo de gran ayuda

Comment: No se si has llegado a leer el ultimo PD. Ten en cuenta que tu entrada de datos también estaba mal planteada. Como la tenías, estabas sobreescribienbdo donde tenias almacenados los paises. El error que te tiraba a ti era en la linea de la impresion, donde tenias tabla[J][J]. Prueba a poner tabla[i][j] y veras que tu error desaparece, pero aún así tu programa no estará funcional, ya que estas pisando el nombre de los paises.

Comment: Ah, y ultima cosa, ten en cuenta que la entrada de los paises también la puedes plantear en un bucle. Con mi solución, fíjate si dándole alguna vuelta consigues hacerlo, ya que te ahorras las p1, p2 y p3 que tienes definidas, a parte de la variable ciudad, que tambien puedes eliminarla haciendo  tabla[i][j] =teclado.nextLine(). No te hace falta almacenar en una variable ciudad temporal.

Answer (score 1):

`No se por qué motivo no me deja editar la respuesta anterior (me tira error de sangrado de código todo el rato por mas que esté correcto, si alguien me la modifica para agregar este código al final de la respuesta anterior, borraré esta, gracias).`

Te dejo el código con las sugerencias que te hago en los comentarios:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\t Aprendiendo Geografia");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        String tabla[][] = new String[3][4];

        for (int i=0;i<tabla.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce el pais numero " + i + ": ");
            tabla[i][0] = teclado.nextLine();
        }
       System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < tabla[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("Introduce la ciudad de " + tabla[i][0] + ": ");
                tabla[i][j] = teclado.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabla[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(tabla[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

De este modo, independientemente de las dimensiones que declares de tabla, tu código seguirá funcionando.